# how can refresh a datagrid from another form without close form 2 or show form 1

Tags: c#, search, datagrid

i have 2 form(form1 and form 2)
form1 has a datagridview and form2 has a textbox , how i can refresh form1 and search txtbox without reload or show form1, my mean is form2 is a searchbox , how i can control datagrid of form1 in form2?

```
private void datagrid_users_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {


        win_searchuser baz = new win_searchuser() ;
        baz.searchname = datagrid_users.Columns[datagrid_users.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].HeaderText;
        baz.columnname = datagrid_users.Columns[datagrid_users.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Name;

        baz.ShowDialog();

    }
```

form2

```
private void txt_name_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var query = data.Database.SqlQuery<vw_users>("Select * from vw_users where "+columnname+" like '%"+txt_name.Text+"%'");
        var u = query.ToList();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = u;
        users tt = new users();

         tt.datagrid_users.DataSource = this.dataGridView1.DataSource;




    }
```

Comment: i change datagrid to public , but not work my sourse and datagrid in form1 not change

Answer (score 0):

[stackoverflow.com/questions/16980077/refreshing-datagridview-from-another-form-on-button-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980077/refreshing-datagridview-from-another-form-on-button-click)

Or you can use delegate

[stackoverflow.com/questions/17478889/refresh-datagridview-records-from-another-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478889/refresh-datagridview-records-from-another-form)

Comment: not true , this is work when you push button , but i need change the datagrid in time when change text in text box

Comment: Mishe shomare mobile ya telegrametono bedid?

Comment: من يه فرم دارم كه داخلش ديتا گريد هست، وقتي روي گريد كليد ميكنيم يه فرم ديگه باز ميشه كه بشه از تكس باكس داخل فرم دوم عمليات سرچ رو توي فرم اول انجام داد ، يعني همينطوري كه تايپ ميكني ديتاگريد فرم اول فيلتر بشه، اما فيلتر نميشه ، مشكل اينجاست كه همزمان تغيير نميكنن حتما بايد فرم اول توسط دكمه يا هرچيزي show بشه، اما من نميخوام show انجام بدم ، شما ميدوني تو اين شرايط بدون show كردن يك فرم چطوري ميشه عمليات همزمان انجام داد؟